# IOS/Android Push Notifications - Basic question

Tags: android, push-notification

I don't know if this question has already been answered. In my IOS/Android app, I wanted to monitor a URL for updates (for example, UPS Tracking). I would like to know if I'm using a API for tracking parcels, and even if the provider says that they don't support Push Notification, is there any other way for my app to enable Push Notifications? All I need is get notified by APN or Android Push notification when there is a change in the package status even if the provider doesn't support it.

Also, is this possible with Urban Airship?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, I think the recommended solution is to use a [service](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) to periodically check the URL for updates and if the status has changed, push a [notification](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to the user from your service.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. Can you elaborate? What do you exactly mean by a service? Please let me know whether my understanding is correct: To check the URL for updates, can I send the URL to urban airship to let UA check for updates and if there are updates, get notified to my app on the phone?

Comment: See the [FAQ about Android push notifications](http://ow.ly/50Sdx) on the Urban Airship website, Android does not support UA push notifications out of the box, it needs an helper application (AirMail control panel) which needs to be installed seperately. So to answer your question: you cannot send push notifications directly to an Android device without third party apps. A service is a process that runs in the background of your application, see the [Android SDK documentation for more info.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/services.html)

Comment: I cannot speak for IOS btw, I think you'll need to make seperate implementations for IOS and Android.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally, you will need to build your own backend server to sendout notifications using Googles C2DM service: http://code.google.com/android/c2dm/index.html

I'd assume you'd send the paracel ID to your server, capture it, then check for  updates periodically. Then, once the status has changed, leverage C2DM and push out the notification to your client.

If you choose to have a service on the device check for this, I'd be cautious - you can easily chew up a lot of expensive data transfer, for not a lot of value.