# Can a Java server work with Java and Objective C objects using a socket?

Tags: java, android, objective-c, push

I am planning to develop a Java server to share info (serialized objects) among Android devices. I need push technology, which I will implement with the Observer Pattern in the server, registering all active devices. Of course, I would use serializable Java objects and there should be no problems here...

But, will I have problems if I want to use this same server with Apple devices too? Or will this kind of architecture only work in a Java environment? I do not know if `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` in the server socket will be able to deal with the received Objective C objects and if Apple devices will be able to deal with Java objects sent by the server.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: [Push notifications in iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH1-SW1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using REST or SOAP there are pleanty of API out there, instead of Object Streams - those will not work as neither Java nor Objective-C is able to handle non Native Serialized Objects.

Comment: I had thought about this option, but ws do not maintain state, all calls to any ws should be independent. So... how could I keep track of the active devices in order to share the info among all connected devices?

Comment: Long Polling may be an option - it is commenly used in similar web applications...

Comment: Have a look at this stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6099054/ios-android-push-notifications-basic-question

Comment: Also there are Java API for IOS and Android push notifications - even so you will need to seperate implementations...

Comment: Ok, so from what you say I should use some kind of third party API. Is there anyone that works with Android and iOS with the same implementation? Thanks.

Comment: Let me google that for you: https://www.google.com/search?q=java+ios+android+push+api&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:de:official&client=firefox-a - intrestingly enough there is a stackoverflow entry that should help you...

Comment: Of course I know how to Google, this is an expected skill in a programmer! I wanted to know your experiences to do the best choice. I have accepted your answer because you've given me a right clue on how to go on! :)

Answer (score 1):

java streams works with java platform only. You cant transfer object using ObjectInputStream/ObjectOutStream with objective C. But there are other solutions you can use to connect with objective c like like you can sent text data via XMLfiles of u can use SOA architecture using HTTP protocol to sent and receive data via web services and data format can be either in xml/json with is understandable by both plateforms

Comment: Now I have the same question as in the other answer... How can I keep track of devices connected to the server if ws do not have state?

Comment: this can be done by your own programming logic, create a a map or list according to your requirement, to set or remove attribute if it is added on other side of the application and sync the state of both application accordingly